# Is there a way to have a richtextbox display the highlight when it loses focus?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a richtextbox, when I leave it for example to go to another panel where I want to manipulate the selected text I can no longer see the selected text.  Is there a way to make it still show the highlight?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642498/how-to-keep-wpf-textbox-selection-when-not-focused).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the RichTextBox's [HideSelection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection%28VS.90%29.aspx) to `false`.

Comment: Not actually a good idea, the user can no longer reliably tell that the RTB has the focus.  But good enough for the OP probably.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I've been looking for hours and I missed that.