# Enable cursor show up and blinking

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my Windows form application, I have a RichTextBox and a couple of other controls. What I want is after I type some words in the text box then I move the cursor outside of the box, afterwards hit the HOME keystroke. The cursor should return the beginning of the text in the RichTextBox.

I finished this part and works out perfectly.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            Cursor.Position = richTextBox1.PointToScreen(richTextBox1.Location);
        }
    }
```

However I can't see the cursor, of course no blinking at all.
Adding the following code is not working.

```
Cursor.Show();
```

My question is how to enable the cursor shows up?

Comment: I think the cursor only shows up when the RichTextBox has focus.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873563/how-to-show-cursor-in-unfocused-winforms-textbox-richtextbox

Comment: `Cursor` is the mouse arrow, you probably mean the text cursor?

Comment: It's called a Caret, not a Cursor.  Just call `richTextBox1.Select();`

Comment: @CommuSoft, yes, maybe. I don't know the precise name.

Comment: @LarsTech, there is no `richTextBox1.Select()` method.

Comment: It would be a bit confusing if you didn't just return focus to the RichTextBox at the same time as you move the cursor back. If you don't, your users will try to type in the box because it will appear to have focus.

Comment: Sure there is.  All controls have that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for stupid, by the hint of the comments. The control should be focused. Just add one line code:

```
richTextBox1.Focus();
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        richTextBox1.Select();
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        Cursor.Position = richTextBox1.PointToScreen(richTextBox1.Location);
    }
}
```

This will set the Selection start and then select the Rich Text Box. Now if there is no focus even after the Select() method is called, Focus() method will ensure that the control gets the focus.

Hope this works...