# Keep Silverlight TextBox Selection Shows while not focused?

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, textbox, visualstates

As titled, and basically I wanted to do the same thing as [this for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642498/how-to-keep-wpf-textbox-selection-when-not-focused) but in Silverlight instead.

But in my TextBox.LostFocus event, there is no e.Handled.  And I also tried to use VisualStateManger.GoToState to Focused State:

```
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(TextBox1, "Focused", false);
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = 3;
        TextBox1.SelectionForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

But it doesn't work either.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will select all on focus.

```
TextBox1.Select(0, TextBox1.Text.Length);
```

Perhaps using this method to set selection. If the selection doesn't persist, try storing your caret position and length in a temporary variable (within a custom textbox class).